# Streptococcus pyogenes mutation and recurrence

Tags: infection, bacteria, antibiotics

Does the bacteria that cause strep throat also mutates, just like the virus that cause flu?

In the same season, is it possible for a person to be infected multiple times (concurrently or not) by the group of bacteria that cause strep throat?

Considering no antibiotics were administered, the fact that the infection in the throat has ended, does it mean the causing bacteria is gone if there no other visible signs of infection? If not, how a patient can rest assured that the bacteria is no longer in her/his system, since no antibiotics were used? Only via blood test?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just tucking a comment in that some people (myself included) seem to get chronic step. I usually pick it up once a year and at this point keep amox and prednisone in the fridge ready to go. I've looked into tonsillectomies but the risk/reward seems mixed and inconclusive. No idea how I keep catching it, entirely possible someone close is an asymptomatic carrier. Or fate just likes to laugh at me.